# How to move a tablview row?

Tags: iphone

I am making an app in which I want to move the row.So I can do it by

[self.tableList setEditing:YES animated:YES];

where "**tableList**" is my table's name but whenever I am running this line.I am not able to get the icon for move which usually comes at right side for moving a cell instead I am getting the icon to delete a row which comes on left side of a cell.

Please help me to get my cell move and ask if you need any clarification of my question..

Thanks.

Comment: did you find solution to ur ans?

Comment: can show us screen shot of ur out put. or else can u expand ur question little bite more???

Comment: use editing style and read the link for more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement the below two methods

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    return YES;

}

    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath {

    //do code according to your requirements of app
 //if you do not write ant thing in the method then also your row will be moved.
        NSString *stringToMove = [[self.dataArray objectAtIndex:sourceIndexPath.row] retain];
        [self.dataArray removeObjectAtIndex:sourceIndexPath.row];
        [self.dataArray insertObject:stringToMove atIndex:destinationIndexPath.row];
        [stringToMove release];
        [tableView reloadData];

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use this link of aple and scrol down to apple how to move or scrol rows. cheerz :)

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

– beginUpdates
– endUpdates
– insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:
– deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:
– moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:
– insertSections:withRowAnimation:
– deleteSections:withRowAnimation:
– moveSection:toSection:

– scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:
– scrollToNearestSelectedRowAtScrollPosition:animated:

Answer (score 0):

use these two method for row move

```
 - (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath
```

Comment: ok Welcome Buddy if it is helpful for you then please mark the right sign and up the arrow on my answer so it will be helpful for other thanks.